# Dropdown in Group widget : ArcGIS Web AppBuilder 2.22

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am using ArcGIS web AppBuilder 2.22 version to create a group widget with dropdown option like shown in attached image. But after searching in Esri forums and googling I could not find anything related to it for Web AppBuilder 2.22 version. In new version I am not getting dropdown in group widget but in same group widget page both widget are opening. I have made group widget of Bookmark for Bookmark_2 and Bookmark .

I am looking for dropdown in group widget like below group widget but its appearing like another screenshot below it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group widgets by dragging and dropping them onto one another while configuring your application. See the below picture. If I drag the widget onto another one, it'll create the group. You can see in the 2nd set I've already created the group.

[image]

After the group is created, to get them to appear in a drop down, click the pencil icon on the Header controller:

[image]

Then select the **Show in drop-down menu** option:
[image]

Comment: I tried your method but when widget are added as group widget, on that group widget dropdown does not appear. In same widget window you will have both measure and legend widget. If I get the dropdown then in dropdown I can see measure and legend widget as separate and then if I click on measurement widget it will open up.

Comment: I have added more description in my question, do I need to make any changes in widget html or in main config.json file.

Comment: @TARUNPUNETHA I've added more details on how to achieve this. see my edit

Comment: that helpful, thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @TARUNPUNETHA Please be sure to click the check mark as an accepted answer

Comment: from portal with your help now I know how to add dropdown in widgets. Can you also help me how to add dropdown in a application widget built on developer edition web appbuilder hosted on IIS.